# Ideal order to study EE

Tags: homework

I'm currently studying Electrical Engineering (second year), and  I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge.

What would be the ideal order of topics (Ohm's law, capacitors, sinusoidal steady-state analysis, etc.) that I can study which will maximise my understanding of the topic?

Comment: Get a copy of Art of Electronics and use that order

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a specific technical question

Answer (score 2):

Crucial in studying EE is to mix the world of hardware with the world of theory.

Seeing results, waveforms, measurements with meters, lab work, is crucial to strengthen how the brain builds a strong wall of interlocking concepts. And read the available free literature: amateur (may be just the right level of clarity of explanation), professional, research, hobbyist.

Another way to express this ------ BUILD CIRCUITS and tinker.

Renee deCartes in his 4_steps_to_understanding (or similar words) bluntly requires the student (of whatever age) to

- consider all possible aspects, in all possible ways, all possible abstractions, all possible phenomena
- whenever some new idea or result or fact, or rumor, arrives, then the student is to think thru all the possibilities, completely, yet again

In other words, to be a skilled explorer of concepts, to manage risks, its the responsibility to immerse and never stop learning.

Societies that do not encourage their people to continual_learning will always be buying the products from societies that DO encourage continual_learning.

Of such skills is the wealth_of_nations.